# How to add Emoji in code?

Tags: xcode, emoji

In Xcode, I've previously gone to Editor > Emoji & Symbols, found some Emoji, double clicked it and had it appear in my code where the cursor is.

I'm trying to do that now and nothing is happening. I can't find any way to get the Emoji into Xcode.

Does anyone have some suggestion?

Comment: How about this: copy in Text Edit and paste it to Xcode.

Answer (score 173):

This solution is for Mac OS (Mavericks and up) and not only Xcode:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Will bring this menu, where you can simply click on the one you want:

[image: emoji picker menu]

Comment: For Windows → "windows button" + "."

Comment: Cmd+Ctrl+Space no longer appears to work in Visual Studio Code 1.65.0, instead it's fn+e.

Comment: Cmd+Ctrl+Space sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. :/ If I choose "Emoji & Symbols" from the Edit menu, I see a globe symbol + E. I'm guessing this is the same as "fn+e" that the above commenter mentioned (but I'm not sure). Choosing from the dropdown menu works for me, hitting fn+e writes "e" for me.

Answer (score 19):

Open Xcode -> Edit Menu -> Choose [image]

Then Emoji appears , Here is snapshot :

[image]

Note : - Xcode 7.2.1

Hope it Helps. Thanks

Comment: None of you have read the OP. You're all showing to get to the Emojis, which I've already described.

Answer (score 0):

To insert emojis in Visual Studio Code, you can use the built-in emoji picker:

1. Open a file in Visual Studio Code.
2. Place your cursor where you want to insert the emoji.
3. Press `Windows Key` + `.` (period)

Answer (score -1):

While using Windows in Atom use <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> for the emojis options.

Answer (score -1):

After searching alot how to insert an emoji in vs code on windows I found out that you have to use <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>.

Answer (score -2):

For adding any emoji in VSCode, follow the steps:

1 Install the extension "Emoji" in vs code.

2. Whenever you need to add an emoji or any symbol in the code, run the Command Palette and search for "Emoji".
3. A list of emojis will show up. Select your required emoji.