# Little icon images added to span class inside <li> tags?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how this is being done? They have different icon imagery in each list, but I am not able to find any code associated with this, no icon styling, and when I look at the source code, it just shows the little icons there as well.

I wanted to duplicate it, but just not sure how this is being done:
https://www.happyhydro.com/products/happy-hydro-5-x-15-trellis-netting-with-3-zip-ties

Thanks in advance,
Todd

Comment: The first steps when looking into something like this is the View Source the page or better still, inspect the element using Developer Tools in the browser of your choice. Either of those options would have revealed how this is done.

Comment: Yes these are just native text characters essentially. If on mac hit `CMD + CTRL + SPACEBAR`, can add them in as you please! ⛷ note that a lot of production level products do not like this and add in linters to make sure it's not in codebase!

Answer (score 2):

and so are, like `a` and `%`, are just characters (hence why they show up in the source code: They are source code). Your OS may provide a convenient [mechanism for inserting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846897/how-to-add-emoji-in-code) or you can copy/paste them from a [character list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block)).

Answer (score 1):

They're emojis added to the text of the span. For example, the first one: https://emojipedia.org/seedling/

Comment: Hi Ashley, I see it now from the website link you, actually quite easy to add into html...just copy and paste. I was looking at it in developer mode, looking for the unicode, but just saw the emoji image. This helps much, thanks!